# VS 2010 has all of a sudden stopped auto-checking out files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe-2005

For some reason Visual Studio has stopped auto-checking out my edits I do to my project.  I use VS2005 for the source control and have never had any issues with it like this ever.  I haven't made any modifications to the server or my workstation.  Has anyone else experienced this?  It's a bit tedious to manually check out every file I edit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: As it turns out checking out the entire project/solution and checking it back in fixed this issue. It seems to be an issue files getting set to read-only outside of VSS' control and you have to force VSS to check out everything before it will resume doing it automatically

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your configuration in VS2010?
Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Environment -> Checked-in items

Comment: On Edit as well as On Save are set to Check out automatically.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog](http://statestreetgang.net/post/2009/03/Has-automatic-checkout-stopped-working-for-you-%20in-Visual-Studio.aspx) has step by step instructions to resolve it and some background info, but basically his list is:

- Check in everything
- Close visual studio
- Make sure every file is set to read only in the solution directory (set it on the root solution folder and configure it to propagate to children)
- Search for all files under the root projet directory *.user and *.vssscc and delete them
- Open VS and load the solution
- Check everything back out and then check everything back in